# Deployment of a Tensorflow object detection model and serving predicitions

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have a Tensorflow object detection model deployed on Google cloud platform's ML Engine. I have come across [posts](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-part-1-make-your-model-ready-for-serving-776a14ec3198) suggesting Tensorflow Serving + Docker for better performance. I am new to Tensorflow and want to know what is the best way to serve predictions. Currently, the ml engine online predictions have a latency of  >50 seconds. My use case is a User uploading pictures using a mobile app and the getting a suitable response based on the prediction result. So, I am expecting th prediciton latency to come down to 2-3 seconds. What else can I do to make the predictions faster?

Comment: You'll probably get faster inference by hosting your model on a GPU machine. I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think this is currently possible wiht ML Engine. With TensorFlow serving you can do that, for instance if you would host your model inside a kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud ML Engine has recently released GPUs support for Online Prediction (Alpha). I believe that our offering may provide the performance improvements you're looking for. Feel free to sign up here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSexO16ULcQP7tiCM3Fqq9i6RRIOtDl1WUgM4O9tERs-QXu4RQ/viewform?usp=sf_link